Cannot get Jodin3 to launch
wanted to flash custom rom to my Galaxy S7, I could install Heimdall successfully, and in download mode the device gets detected but JOdin3CASUAL.rar file cannot be opened, sometimes it says,
"Java Application launch filed. Check Console for possible error messages related to to "/Users/ysskhn/Downloads/javafx-sdk-22.0.1/lib/javafx.base.jar"
and when I try it in terminal I get;
Error: Could not find or load main class com.casual_dev.jodin.JOdinMain
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
and when I double click it afterwards nothing happens (it opens but instantly quits). I have Java Version 17 installed.

Does this answer your question? Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

@seenukarthi
and how do I add this to my Runtime or whatever it is called ? and there are 2 versions SDK or jmods

Are you using any build tool like maven or gradle and so on..?
